Having trouble understanding Linked List in C
#define SIZE 100000

// 1. hash_function() is a function that return an int

// 2. snowflake_node 
typedef struct snowflake_node {
  int snowflake[6];
  struct snowflake_node *next; 
} snowflake_node;

// 3. main
int main(void) {
  static snowflake_node *snowflakes[SIZE] = { NULL }; 
  snowflake_node *snow;
  int n, i, j, hash_code;

  scanf(“%d”, &n);  
  for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    snow = malloc(sizeof(snowflake_node));
    if (snow == NULL) {
      fprintf(stderr, ”malloc error\n”);
      exit(1);
    }  
    for (j = 0; j < 6; j++)
      scanf(“%d”, &snow->snowflake[j]);
  
    hash_code = hash_function(snow->snowflake);
    snow->next = snowflakes[hash_code];

    // 4. This confuses me
    snowflakes[hash_code] = snow;  
  }  

  return 0; 
}

So, I am still trying to grasp how I can implement a Linked List in C. I quite understand that each node in a Linked List has a pointer to the next.
What confuses me is that number 4 part. Let's say that the first Snow has the hash_code of 21. This is going to be pointer to it.
It turns out that the second Snow also has the hash_code of 21. If we apply it to the code:
snowflakes[hash_code] = snow
Does that mean we replace the current Snow with the new one, instead of chaining them all together?

Use a pencil and paper, and trace what your code is doing. Use (labeled) boxes for variables and nodes, and arrows for pointers. Erase and redraw the arrows as you modify the pointers. Hopefully that will help you visualize what's going on.

formally this is not linked list, it's some kind of hash table that uses linked list structure. Linked list doesn't have random access abilty (the line in question) or hashing function.

@Swift-FridayPie, yes it isn't. That's why I get confused. I learned it from "Algorithmic Thinking, Problem Based Introduction". I came across the first problem and it uses this hash tables. So, each elements of an Array has index, and each indices has a Linked List chained together (?).

Do you understand linked lists in general? If not then please start with that. Then this implementation of a hash-table will become much easier to understand.

@arifnone, Note that hash_function() will be a problem if it returns a value outside the [0... SIZE) range.  Consider changing hash_code = hash_function(snow->snowflake) into hash_code = hash_function(snow->snowflake)%(unsigned)SIZE to insure the index is in range.

snowflakes array:
static snowflake_node *snowflakes[SIZE] = {NULL};

In-memory view of snowflakes array would be something like this:
snowflakes
     +----+
[0]  |  --|----> NULL
     +----+
[1]  |  --|----> NULL
     +----+
[2]  |  --|----> NULL
     +----+
       .
       .
       .
       .
     +----+
[N]  |  --|----> NULL
     +----+

 where value of N is (SIZE - 1).

Assume that, in the first iteration of for loop, allocating memory to pointer snow, the pointer returned by malloc() is 100 :
snow            snowflake_node
   +----+       +-------------------+
   | 100|------>|  |  |  | .... |   |
   +----+       +-------------------+
               100

Assume hash_function() returns value 2 for argument snow->snowflake:
hash_code = hash_function(snow->snowflake);
// hash_code value is 2

In this statement:
snow->next = snowflakes[hash_code];

snow->next will be assigned NULL because snowflakes[2] is NULL.
Now, this statement will execute:
snowflakes[hash_code] = snow;

which will assign the value of snow pointer to snowflakes[2] pointer. The snowflakes array in-memory view would be something like this:
snowflakes
     +----+
[0]  |  --|----> NULL
     +----+
[1]  |  --|----> NULL
     +----+     +-------------------+
[2]  | 100|---->|  |  |  | .... | --|-->NULL 
     +----+     +-------------------+
       .       100                |
       .                          +-> next pointer of snowflake_node
       . 
       .
     +----+
[N]  |  --|----> NULL
     +----+

Now, assume that, in the second iteration of for loop, the pointer returned by malloc() is 200:
snow            snowflake_node
   +----+       +-------------------+
   | 200|------>|  |  |  | .... |   |
   +----+       +-------------------+
               200 

and hash_function() returns value 2 for argument snow->snowflake.
In this statement:
snow->next = snowflakes[hash_code];   // value of hash_code is 2

snow->next will be assigned the value of pointer snowflakes[2] which is 100 as the pointer snowflakes[2] pointing to memory location 100.
this statement:
snowflakes[hash_code] = snow;

will assign the value of snow pointer to snowflakes[2] pointer. The snowflakes array in-memory view would be something like this:
snowflakes
     +----+
[0]  |  --|----> NULL
     +----+
[1]  |  --|----> NULL
     +----+     +-------------------+   +-------------------+
[2]  | 200|---->|  |  |  | .... |100|-->|  |  |  | .... | --|---> NULL 
     +----+     +-------------------+   +-------------------+
       .       200                      100
       .
       . 
       .
     +----+
[N]  |  --|----> NULL
     +----+



So, the first Snow becomes the last one on the list, because its next points to NULL ? 2) Assuming the hash code keep getting value 2, the snowflakes[2], will point to the newest one?


@arifnone 1) Yes but not because its next point to NULL but because every new node getting inserted at the start of list (at a given index of snowflakes array). Hence, the first node becomes the last one in the list. 2) Yes.

Look at the pair of statements:
snow->next = snowflakes[hash_code];
snowflakes[hash_code] = snow;

The first one sets the next field of the new node to the head of the list at snowflakes[hash_code].  The second one sets snowflakes[hash_code] to the new node.  So any existing linked list pointed to by the old snowflakes[hash_code] now follows the new node.  Nothing is lost.  This is a "push" operation:  The new node is "pushed" onto the head of the list.

This declaration
static snowflake_node *snowflakes[SIZE] = {NULL};

declares a hash table of the size SIZE. Each entry of the table represents a singly linked list that is designed to store nodes with the same calculated hash value. Initially all the linked lists are empty because their pointers to header nodes are initialized by null pointers.
Each new node of the selected entry of the hash table (of the selected linked list)
hash_code = hash_function(snow->snowflake);

is added to the beginning of the list. That is its data member next is set to point to the current header node of the selected list
snow->next = snowflakes[hash_code];

and then the new node becomes the header node
snowflakes[hash_code] = snow;

That is the selected entry of the hash table now contains a pointer to the newly added node for the calculated hash value.
To make the code more clear you could write a separate function named like for example push or push_front that would add a new node for the selected linked list according to the calculated hash value.
Try to do that yourself as an exercise.

This is the first Snow snowflakes[21] = snow;, this is the second Snow with the same hash code snowflakes[21] = snow;. I don't quite understand with this assignment operator. I assume the array of index 21 now is occupied by the second Snow (?).

@arifnone on each iteration, value of snow points to a new obejct (it's still object, even in C), while  snow->next = snowflakes[hash_code]; ensures that previous value is pointed at by next. What you have is a table snowflakes(or rather, a set of "bins"?) of linked lists, a new value always instered as "head" of particular linked list denoted by hash_function.

@arifnone Each new node for a selected singly-linked list (in your example the singly-linked list  that corresponds to the hash value 21) is added to its beginning and becomes a header node of the linked list. Please reread my answer anew. You need at first to learn singly-linked lists.
